# On reboot system asking for keychain password for local items

Tags: icloud, keychain

I reinstalled OS X Yosemite, I am now using a new admin password (I also changed my iCloud account password.) Upon setting up iCloud, it reused the iCloud data.

Everything is running fine BUT on each reboot I am asked to enter the "old iCloud password" for all system agents using the "Local Items".

```
___________ wants to use the "Local Items" keychain. Please enter the keychain password
```

and it only accepts my old iCloud password, not the new one ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Keychain password & login are only the same until you change one, then you need to change the other separately

Source: [OS X: Keychain Access asks for keychain "login" after changing login password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201609)

> Note: This doesn't happen if you change your account password using Accounts preferences.
>   If you want your default keychain to be unlocked automatically when you log in, synchronize your Keychain Access and account login passwords by doing this:
>
> - Open Keychain Access (you can get to it by choosing Utilities from the Go menu in the Finder).
> - From the Edit menu, choose Change Password for Keychain "login."
> - Type the former password of the account that you are currently logged in to, then click OK.
> - If you entered the correct password, a new window appears; enter the original password again in the Current Password field.
> - In the New Password field, type the password that matches your current account password.
> - Re-enter the newer password in the Verify field, then click OK.

Answer (score 1):

I am amazed how much hassle changing my Apple ID password causes me, but the solution I've used for this is from Npalamidis [on the Apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23467647#23467647):

> 1.- Opening KeyChain app
>   2.- Locking the Keychain by clicking the lock on the top left corner.
>   3.- Unlocking the Keychain, as soon as I typed my Admin Password it asked me to "Reset my iCloud KeyChain" I clicked yes because I didn't
>   have setup my icloud keychain yet.
>   4.- Restart computer.
>   After performing this steps the computer restarted flawlessly and without 
>   asking for the "Local Items" password.

I locked and unlocked all the keychains because there wasn't one listed called "local" but following [Tetsujin's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177470/142445) I'll try just the login one next time.

Answer (score -1):

The other solutions didn't work for me.

For the first one, changing the keychain password, I found the keychain was using the right password, so I was changing the right password... with the right password? It still used the old password on restart.

Then I saw another keychain called 'Local Items' and I thought that might be it, I clicked it, unlocked it and it disappeared (all fairy tale like). Then I didn't know what to do; the second solution didn't work under any circumstance, the icloud keychain simply wouldn't lock.

What worked for me was to `reset the keychain from Keychain Access > Preferences`, which is fine since you get a backup of your old keychain.

After resetting I `changed the password of the new keychain` and Voilla! it was finally the old pesky password getting changed. Now all is good!